# Exclude a specific set of users from vercel analytics

Tags: next.js, vercel, next.js13, next-auth

I have a NextJS 13.4.16 app deployed on Vercel. It has NextAuth 4.23.1 email authentication ([link](https://next-auth.js.org/providers/email)) and users are managed in a DynamoDB table in AWS ([link](https://authjs.dev/reference/adapter/dynamodb)). I have also enabled Vercel analytics such that I can monitor things like page visits.

Now I want to separate metrics (page visits specifically), for external users and internal users. One way to split could be the email domain.

Is there away to filter Vercel analytics based on custom user category or email domain?